# From API to Django template to show different data while iterating

Tags: python, django, api, django-views, django-templates

```
 ***This is view function***    
    def home_view(request):
            url = "https://random-recipes.p.rapidapi.com/ai-quotes/50"
        
            headers = {
                "X-RapidAPI-Key": "`enter code here`",
                "X-RapidAPI-Host": "random-recipes.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
        
            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
            res = response
        
            context = {'res' : change_recipe(), 'iterator':range(0,11)}
        
            return render(request,'home.html', context=context)
```

***This is django template***

```
<div class="container" id="card" >
    {% for i in iterator %}
    <div class="card1">
        <div class="card-header1">
            <img src="{{res.image}}" alt="rover" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body1">
            <h4>
                <a href="/article/" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit; " >{{res.title}}</a>
            </h4>
            <p>
                An exploration into the truck's polarising design
            </p>
            <div class="user1">
                <div class="user-info1">
                    <strong>By</strong>
                    <a href="">Rachel Lucas</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**I want to show different data when iterating for loop in django template using api**
when I replace res with res[0] it show only one data in all card1/div after iterating for loop in django template, i want to show different data in different cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change **res** in your template to **res[i]**